# Wildfly 14 setting up PostgreSQL Datasource - FATAL: database "my_user" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, wildfly

I have a PostgreSQL database running called `my_db`. I can connect to this database via `psql` and HeidiSQL.

I have a Wildfly 14 server running and have added the PostgreSQL JDBC Driver as as a deployment (I can see the driver listed under the Configuration > Datasources & Drivers > JDBC Drivers).

I am trying to create a Datasource for my application but it is not working.

```
Name: MyDS
JNDI Name: java:/MyDS
Connection URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db
Username: my_user
Password: my_password
```

But when I test the connection I get the error:

`FATAL: database "my_user" does not exist`

It is able to authenticate the user role `my_user` but for some reason it is trying to connect to the database `my_user` rather than `my_db`.

What am I doing wrong? I need it to connect to the db `my_db`.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't understand why it was ignoring the `my_db` part in the Connection URL until I realised that it was probably ignoring the whole URL. A quick search revealed the following question:

[WildFly Postgres DataSource remote connection-url ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44984640/wildfly-postgres-datasource-remote-connection-url-ignored#44984977)

My Datasource Class was set to `org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource`, deleting this allowed it to work.

The problem was that in Wildfly it did not give an option to set the Datasource Class during the Datasource creation wizard (i.e. Configuration > Datasources & Drivers > DAtasource > Add), so I had to create an invalid Datasource using the wizard and then modify it to remove the Datasource Class `org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource`.

Answer (score 2):

**In the WildFly Admin Console, add the property (Connection Properties field) to the datasource :**

```
url ⇒ jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/<database>
```

**The field 'Connection URL' doesn't work for connecting. It looks like:**

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to press "Enter" to add the connection property, BEFORE you click on "Save"